# I am getting two errors but I cannot identify them

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

I am a novice to c++, but I am doing my best to learn. 
I am getting two errors and I don't know why, these are:

1. In constructor 'MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget*)':
2. Qualified-id in declaration before '(' token -line 7
3. Qualified-id in declaration before '(' token -line20

My code is as follows:

mylabel.cpp:

```
#include "mylabel.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    void MyLabel::MyLabel()
    {
        this->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        //Default Label Value
        this->setText("No Value");

        //set MouseTracking true to capture mouse event even its key is not pressed
        this->setMouseTracking(true);
    }



    void MyLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
    {
        //Show x and y coordinate values of mouse cursor here
        this->setText("X:" + QString::number(event->x()) + "-- Y:" + QString::number(event->y()));
    }


}
```

mylabel.h:

```
#ifndef MYLABEL_H
#define MYLABEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class MyLabel : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyLabel();

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event);

signals:

};

#endif // MYLABEL_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "mylabel.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("QT - Capture Mouse Move"));
    window->resize(300, 250);

    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget(window);
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget);

    MyLabel* CoordinateLabel = new MyLabel();
    layout->addWidget(CoordinateLabel);

    window->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp is blank

Comment: You have member functions defined in the body of the constructor, move them outside of it.

Comment: Using a 3rd-party GUI framework is not exactly the best way to learn the C++ programming language.

Comment: You probably want to subclass QLabel, not QWidget. @ChristianHackl Say what you will, but this is how some of my friends initially learned C++. It's often more interesting to see your app on the screen than some text being outputted, at least.

Comment: @JohnChadwick: I don't say it's impossible. I just say it's a very bad way because you miss out on a lot of basics and will take a lot of Qt-specific idioms as standard idioms.

Comment: Qt with its API, indeed, is a nice way to learn C++. At least for applications that have GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement your custom label you have to derive your class from Qt's standard QLabel class as:

```
class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyLabel();
protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
};
```

Unfortunately in C++ you can not define a function inside another function as you did in `MyLabel::MyLabel()` constructor. Just write it in the following way:

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    //Default Label Value
    setText("No Value");

    //set MouseTracking true to capture mouse event even its key is not pressed
    setMouseTracking(true);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I would implement the handling of the mouse move event in this way:

```
void MyLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    // Show x and y coordinate values of mouse cursor here
    QString txt = QString("X:%1 -- Y:%2").arg(event->x()).arg(event->y());
    setText(txt);
}
```

Comment: Understood, I was not seeing what I was doing there. Now, I have another question how do I implement the function MouseMoveEvent()? I am getting errors saying that it does not identify the members inside it.

Comment: Okay, I see. I did as told but now I am getting the same error I was getting before I asked this question. The error is: undefined reference to 'MyLabel::~MyLabel()' and undefined reference to 'non-virtual thunk to MyLabel::~MyLabel()'

Comment: @JLREng, that's because you declare the destructor `~MyLabel()` but did not define it. Just add `MyLabel::~MyLabel() {}` to your .cpp file or remove `~MyLabel()` declaration from the header file if you are not going to use it.

Comment: Thank you vahancho. I was having another error at which I have solved. in MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent):: QWidget(parent) Qt was giving me an error. Since the code has to set a text in from the base class QLabel it did not find it because the base class is QWidget. So, after replacing the base class QWidget with QLabel, it ran beautifully . Thank you for your help, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error are you are trying to define functions inside your constructor.  `MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent)` so be

```
MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

    //Default Label Value
    this->setText("No Value");

    //set MouseTracking true to capture mouse event even its key is not pressed
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
}
```

And then the definition for `mouseMoveEvent` should follow after the constructor

```
void MyLabel::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    //Show x and y coordinate values of mouse cursor here
    this->setText("X:" + QString::number(event->x()) + "-- Y:" + QString::number(event->y()));
}
```

EDIT:

As pointed out in the comments `setAlignment` and `setText` are not members of `QWidget` so if they are not members of `MyLable` then you will need to remove those otherwise it will not compile.

Comment: This will not compile because `QWidget` class does not have `setText()` and  `setAlignment()` functions.

Comment: Okay, I see. 
I did as told but now I am getting the same error I was getting before I asked this question. The error is: undefined reference to 'MyLabel::~MyLabel()' and undefined reference to 'non-virtual thunk to MyLabel::~MyLabel()'